# How do I make a list by iterating object type record?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a `neo4j` object type record .it contains
`[name, country, value]`. For every iteration, it produce separate list of items if I `print(list(ith value of record))`.
But I want to  make a whole list  of these list like
`[[name1,country1,value1],[name2,country2,value2]]`. I tried append, but it is somehow didn't work for me. kindly, help me by suggesting some concepts

My current code is this

```
myquery="""MATCH (c :Customer {walletId:$item})-[:MR|:SENDS_MONEY]-(d)-[:PAYS]->(m)
               WHERE NOT (c)-[]-(m)
               RETURN c.walletId, m.walletId, m.name, COUNT(m.name) ORDER BY COUNT(m.name) DESC LIMIT 30"""
        result=graphdbsessionwallet.run(myquery,item=item)
        #print(result)


        for record in  result:

              print(list(record))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
return [[row.name, row.country, row.value]
        for row in query_results]
```